# why does git cherry-pick create a different checksum?

Tags: git

In the following session, why does the result of `git cherry-pick` not have the same checksum as the copied commit?  It has the same comment, author, date, and parent.  What else is in the checksum that I am not accounting for?

Thanks.

```
~$  mkdir tmp
~$ cd tmp/
~/tmp$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/sinclairs/projects/tmp/.git/

~/tmp$ echo "asdf" >asdf
~/tmp$ git add asdf
~/tmp$ git commit -m asdf
[master (root-commit) 7d0aaa3] asdf
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 asdf

~/tmp$ echo "fdsa" >asdf
~/tmp$ git commit -a -m asdf2
[master b392367] asdf2
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

~/tmp$ git log --format=oneline
b3923677106db9371faf55ed2cb8c7d06f586f7f asdf2
7d0aaa3937de390b7a119c73dbf9428126c1bac5 asdf

~/tmp$ git checkout -b mybranch HEAD^
Switched to a new branch 'mybranch'

~/tmp$ git cherry-pick master
Finished one cherry-pick.
[mybranch ca92f66] asdf2
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

~/tmp$ git log --format=oneline
ca92f666cc53715c6b5ae2975b938275e0d20f73 asdf2
7d0aaa3937de390b7a119c73dbf9428126c1bac5 asdf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Author date is the same but commit date is different.

And you can use this to actually see the difference.

```
git cat-file -p b3923677106db9
git cat-file -p ca92f666cc5371
```

Author line is the same, committer line date is different.

Comment: Yes it is. In the example the parent of both is 7d0aaa3937de390b7a119c73dbf9428126c1bac5.

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry-pick.html) :

```
git cherry-pick master
    Apply the change introduced by the commit at the tip of the master branch and create a new commit with this change.
```

The new commit date is different.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you would adjust the commit date (which is possible) the tree and parent are different and you cannot change them!